# How to include "matlabengine.hpp" and "MatlabDataArray.hpp" files in gcc's search path on windows using 64-bits MinGW and 32-bits Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, mingw, matlab-engine

I have a file named `call_mat.cpp` with two statements at its beginning:

```
\#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp" and    \#include "MatlabEngine.hpp"

These headers files are not on "gcc" default search path. They are in the folder "C:/Programmes/MATLAB/R2018a/extern/include". I tried the "-I" option to include them when running my code using the following command:

gcc -c -I/C:/Programmes/MATLAB/R2018a/extern/include call_mat.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
call_mat.cpp:1:10: fatal error: MatlabDataArray.hpp: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this under MSYS2 shell?
If so, you should either use:

```
-IC:/Programmes/MATLAB/R2018a/extern/include
```

or:

```
-I/C/Programmes/MATLAB/R2018a/extern/include
```

or maybe even:

```
-I'C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include'
```

If you're not using any kind of *nix-like shell (or the plain Command Prompt or PowerShell) you can probably use:

```
-I "C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include"
```

Comment: I am using the classical cmd of windows. So, I tried the last command you gave me and it still produces the same error.  

>gcc -c -I"C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include" call_mat.cpp

Comment: I also noticed you use gcc but the include file is a .hpp file. Looks like you should be using g++ instead of gcc...

Comment: Can you try `SET CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include` before you do `g++ -c call_mat.cpp`?

Comment: Still displaying the same error message even after adding 
"SET CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include"

Comment: Are you able to run `DIR C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include\MatlabDataArray.hpp` in a Command Prompt without error?

Comment: Yes, ```lang-none DIR C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include\MatlabDataArray.hpp``` works perfectly.

Comment: @solution: this worked fine for me: ```g++ -I "C:\Programmes\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include" call_mat.cpp```. Thank you all.